# Docker php excel error (php://output) i/o stream

Tags: php, docker, phpexcel

Currently, I am running two servers: one for development and the other for docker service. Under the same environments, when I execute php-fpm in Docker container, php excel that was working in devleopment server is not working in docker service.

The error in the code is below(I cannot identify the error on browser):

```
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('오더내역-'.$d->format('Ymd'));
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.return_date_format(microtime(true)).'_'.count($list).'건의 오더내역'.'.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
```

It seemslike i/o stream error, it does not work only in docker server (works fine in other servers). I want to provide more details such as error log, but there is no such thing.